# Obtener valor siguiente a una ventana movil Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datos

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente set de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La última columna es un cálculo de la columna: "+DM" y es igual a:

```
stockData['Smoothed +DM']=stockData["+DM"].rolling(3).sum()- stockData["+DM"].rolling(3).mean() + stockData["+DM"].rolling(3+1).value()
```

Donde:

- stockData["+DM"].rolling(3).sum() = Suma movil de las últimas 3 filas
- stockData["+DM"].rolling(3).mean() = Promedio movil de las últimas 3
  filas
- stockData["+DM"].rolling(3+1).value()= Valor siguiente a una ventana
  movil de las últimas 3 filas

> stockData["+DM"].rolling(3+1).value(): Se que esta función no existe,
> pero conocen alguna función que me pueda entregar el valor siguiente a
> una ventana movil?

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Si únicamente buscas obtener el valor de la fila siguiente entonces podrías utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Como no pusiste los datos como texto, cree un ejemplo genérico:

```
   +DM
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
9   10
```

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'+DM':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
df['Smoothed +DM'] = df['+DM'].rolling(3).sum() - df['+DM'].rolling(3).mean() + df['+DM'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Utilizamos `shift()` para obtener el valor de la fila siguiente de cada celda y `fillna()` para rellenar con cero el valor de la última fila

Esto devuelve:

```
   +DM  Smoothed +DM
0    1           NaN
1    2           NaN
2    3           8.0
3    4          11.0
4    5          14.0
5    6          17.0
6    7          20.0
7    8          23.0
8    9          26.0
9   10          18.0
```

**Nota:** Cambiando el valor de `-1` en `shift(-1)` puedes defasar `n` número de celdas, por lo que si requires en la fila 1 el valor de la fila 4 podrías utilizar `-3`

Comment: He probado su recomendación y funciona perfecto!

Comment: Que bien! Para la próxima por favor agrega tus datos como texto, no como imagen para que así podamos reutilizar la información. Un ejemplo del resultado también es útil para saber si lo que entendimos de tu pregunta es correcto. Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).